# Python: 'get_costed_productions' Object Does Not Support Indexing

Tags: python, nltk

```
def get_costed_productions(psents):
    """ Creates costed/weighted productions from a given list of parsed sentences."""
    prods_dict = production_distribution(psents)
    prods_nt_counts=nt_counts(prods_dict)
    costed_prods=[CostedProduction(p.lhs(),p.rhs(),production_cost(p, prods_nt_counts, prods_dict))
               for p in prods_dict.keys()]
    return costed_prods

prods = get_costed_productions(psents)
ppg=PCFG(Nonterminal('NP'), prods)
sprods = ppg.productions(Nonterminal('S'))
npprods = ppg.productions(Nonterminal('VP'))

nps = filter(lambda prod: prod[1].lhs().symbol() == 'NP', list(prods))
rhs = map(lambda x: x[1], nps)
rhs_dist = nltk.FreqDist(rhs)
print len(rhs_dist.keys())
print rhs_dist.tabulate()
```

Getting error: `get_costed_productions` Object Does Not Support Indexing
What changes do I need to do in   get_costed_productions function to resolve this issue?

Comment: What actually the function get_costed_productions returns? make sure that it returns something like list or tuple which can be indexed by calling the print type(prods)

Comment: @VijayabhaskarJ I have updated the question with `get_costed_productions` function

Comment: what does print type(prods) and print len(prods) print?

Comment: `prods` - return list of production and `len` return length of the productions

Comment: The message means you're trying to use your function as if it's a list. It _probably_ means you are applying square brackets instead of round brackets to your function somewhere, but that cannot be seen in the code you posted. You should edit your question and include the full stack trace from the error. Without full code *or* the error, there's nothing to see.